# Cannot remote debug in docker with Goland

Tags: docker, go, goland

I'm trying to remote debug a go application in a docker container, and I followed the steps of [this ariticle](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2020/05/06/debugging-a-go-application-inside-a-docker-container/).
But when I click the debug button, it immediately shows that "[Remote process terminated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BwcY.png)", and the program in Docker runs normally but [no breakpoints are triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2x4N.png). and I don't know where is the problem.
Could someone tell me where the problem is and how to solve it? Thanks!

I'm using Goland 2022.1.3 and Docker Desktop v4.10.1 in Windows 10.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
# 编译阶段
FROM golang:1.18 AS build-env

## 换国内源->构建调试工具Delve
RUN go env -w GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn && \
    go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

## 将当前目录拷贝至目标容器
COPY . /tempdir
## 切换工作目录
WORKDIR /tempdir
## 编译go文件
RUN go build -o /tp -gcflags="all=-N -l" temp.go

# 运行阶段
FROM debian:buster
## 暴露调试的端口
EXPOSE 23555
WORKDIR /
## 将构建的编译镜像中的dlv调试工具程序和exp程序拷贝到当前容器
COPY --from=build-env /go/bin/dlv /
COPY --from=build-env /tp /
## 执行调试命令
CMD ["/dlv", "--listen=:23555", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--accept-multiclient", "exec", \
"/tp", "100"]
```

This is my code `Temp.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("need 1 args")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var s []int
    printSlice(s)

    // 添加一个空切片
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("arg 1 error")
        os.Exit(2)
    }
    s = append(s, i)
    printSlice(s)

    // 这个切片会按需增长
    s = append(s, 1)
    printSlice(s)

    // 可以一次性添加多个元素
    s = append(s, 2, 3, 4)
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

This is my [Dockerfile configurations in Goland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfPOE.png).
And this is my [Go Remote configurations in Goland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKD91.png).

Comment: Please also add the `docker run` command you use and share the GoLand run config settings as well.

Comment: The `docker run` command I use is in the image [Dockerfile configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfPOE.png) mentioned above, should be equivalent to `docker run --name=exprc -p 23555:23555 --security-opt="apparmor=unconfined" --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE expp`, thanks

Comment: Could you please share the location of where are you setting up breakpoints?

Comment: I set a breakpoint on line 28 `s = append(s, 1)`.  Can't a breakpoint be set anywhere in the source file? I just randomly set a breakpoint. And I've tried setting breakpoints in many places, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Tried to reproduce it with your Go file and Dockerfile to no avail. Do you see any logs in _Services | Docker | Containers | Container Name | Log_ tab?

Comment: I've tried many times but it doesn't work. I'm sorry that I'm a newer and can not post images directly but can only use the link. The image of the container log is mentioned above, and the link is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2x4N.png).  The program runs normally but no breakpoints are triggered.

Comment: Did you try some suggestions from here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10461 ?